# Leica ScanStation C10 output file format

Tags: 3d, file-format, point-clouds, lidar

This is Leica's proprietary file format they have not published. Their own (Windows only) software called Cyclone has to be used to process the data from ScanStation.

Can anybody provide any hints about internal structure of those .bin files?

Comment: related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113877/open-source-reader-of-leica-c10-terrestrial-lidar-proprietary-file-format